# Dropping tables taking to much time in MySql

Tags: mysql, performance, bulk

I am working on bulk data insertions without using Traction Scope. Data dumped into staging tables from data files then loaded & processed to other tables. 
After process completed. staging tables are taking too much time on DROP statement. when I run the same statement before main process then it does not take any time to drop same tables that contains same number of records of last process.

The same statement takes no time when I execute it before bulk insertion and process queries. but it takes much more time when I execute after process.